# Constructing an immersion of a curve with certain properties

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the map $\gamma : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ given by $(t^2, t^3)$. Let $Gr(1,T\mathbb R^2) := \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb R^2} Gr(1,T_x \mathbb R^2)$ where $Gr(1,T_x \mathbb R^2)$ is the Grassmannian.

If we let $\pi : Gr(1,T\mathbb R^2) \to \mathbb R^2$ denote the canonical projection then I would like to find a map $\widetilde{\gamma}: \mathbb R \to Gr(1,T\mathbb R^2)$ such that

$$ \gamma = \pi \circ \widetilde{\gamma}$$

Note that $\gamma' = (2t, 3t^2) = 2t (1, {3\over 2}t)$.

In the example the map $\widetilde{\gamma}$ is chosen to be

$$ \widetilde{\gamma} = (\gamma, {3\over 2}t) = (t^2, t^3, {3\over 2}t)$$

But it seems to me that

$$ \widetilde{\gamma} = (t^2, t^3, 2t^4)$$

or

$$ \widetilde{\gamma} = (t^2, t^3, -t)$$

would be equally valid immersions with the property $\widetilde{\gamma} = \pi \circ \gamma$.

> What am I missing? Or if they indeed are valid immersions too, why would it be particularly desirable to choose the last coordinate of the derivative to be the last coordinate of the immersion?

**Added**

We want the following to hold:

Let $f: U \subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$.

Then for every $u \in U$ there exists a neighbourhood $u \in W \subset U$ and linearly independent vector fields $v_1, \dots, v_n$ along $f$ such that

$$ \langle {\partial f \over \partial x_1}, \dots, {\partial f \over \partial x_n}\rangle  \subset \langle v_1, \dots, v_n \rangle$$

at every point $w \in W$

if and only if

there exists an immersion $\widetilde{f}: U \to GR(n, T\mathbb R^m)$ such that $f = \pi \circ \widetilde{f}$.

Comment: Your first $\tilde \gamma$ can be used as it is not an immersion at $t=0$. Your second $\tilde \gamma$ is fine. Indeed, the $\tilde \gamma$ given in the example has a geometric meaning: $\frac 32 t$ represent the slope of $(t^2, t^3)$ (or the tangent line).

Comment: @John I see! Thank you for your comment!

Comment: I meant to say "can't be used" in the first line.

Comment: @John Yeah, I assumed :-)

Comment: @John Isn't the slope of $(t^2, t^3)$ given by ${3 \over 2} \sqrt{t}$ rather than ${3\over 2}t$?

Comment: The tangent is $\tilde \gamma' (t) = (2t, 3t^2) = 2t(1, \frac 32 t)$. So the tangent line is given by $(1, \frac 32 t)$ (or just $\frac 32 t$, as you wrote)

Comment: @John Interesting... I "solved for y" in the following sense: $$ t^2 = y^2 = t^3 $$ hence $$ y = t^{3 \over 2}$$ The derivative of which is $$y' = {3\over 2} \sqrt{t}$$

I wonder why this approach doesn't work. (I see I had accidentally switched the $x$- and the $y$-axis but if we don't switch them it should work: $$ y^3 = t^2$$ hence $$ y = t^{2\over 3}$$ so that $$ y' = {2\over 3} t^{- 1 \over 3}$$
Unfortunately this is false, too)

Comment: Indeed I don't quite understand your calculations: how is $y^3 = t^2$?

Comment: @John Well, $\gamma (t) = (x(t) , y(t))$. I'm thinking of $y$ as a function of $x$... do you know what I mean?

Comment: You can either write $x^3 = y^2$ or just $(t^2, t^3)$. But it is not so clear what is $y^3 = t^2$..

Comment: @John Ok, I meant $x^3 = y^2$. Then we'd have $y  = x^{3 \over 2}$ and therefore $y' = {3\over 2}\sqrt{x} \neq {3 \over 2} x$. But since $t$ is the independent variable, that is, same as $x$, we should have $y' =  {3 \over 2} x$.

Comment: But then $x = t^2$, so $\frac 32 \sqrt x = \frac 32 t$.

Comment: @John I see what I did there. :-) Thank you very much for your comments!